# Python 3: How to submit an async function to a threadPool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I want to use both `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures` and async functions.

My program repeatedly submits a function with different input values to a thread pool. The final sequence of tasks that are executed in that larger function can be in any order, and I don't care about the return value, just that they execute at some point in the future.

So I tried to do this

```
async def startLoop():

    while 1:
        for item in clients:
            arrayOfFutures.append(await config.threadPool.submit(threadWork, obj))

        wait(arrayOfFutures, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
```

where the function submitted is:

```
async def threadWork(obj):
   bool = do_something() # needs to execute before next functions
   if bool:
       do_a() # can be executed at any time
       do_b() # ^
```

where `do_b` and `do_a` are async functions.The problem with this is that I get the error: `TypeError: object Future can't be used in 'await' expression` and if I remove the await, I get another error saying I need to add `await`.

I guess I could make everything use threads, but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: Don't fully understand your question. If you use threadpool to execute async functions, you take no advantage. So what is the point?

Comment: @Sraw Not everything being executed is async, only a couple functions at the end. I don't want to spawn heaps of threads to handle this, so I thought I might be able to get the last two running async within the spawned thread.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recommend a careful readthrough of Python 3's [asyncio development guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html), particularly the "Concurrency and Multithreading" section.

The main conceptual issue in your example that event loops are single-threaded, so it doesn't make sense to execute an async coroutine in a thread pool.  There are a few ways for event loops and threads to interact:

- Event loop per thread.  For example:

  ```
   async def threadWorkAsync(obj):
       b = do_something()
       if b:
           # Run a and b as concurrent tasks
           task_a = asyncio.create_task(do_a())
           task_b = asyncio.create_task(do_b())
           await task_a
           await task_b

   def threadWork(obj):
       # Create run loop for this thread and block until completion
       asyncio.run(threadWorkAsync())

   def startLoop():
       while 1:
           arrayOfFutures = []
           for item in clients:
               arrayOfFutures.append(config.threadPool.submit(threadWork, item))

           wait(arrayOfFutures, timeout=None, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
  ```
- Execute blocking code in an executor. This allows you to use async futures instead of concurrent futures as above.

  ```
   async def startLoop():
       while 1:
           arrayOfFutures = []
           for item in clients:
               arrayOfFutures.append(asyncio.run_in_executor(
                   config.threadPool, threadWork, item))

           await asyncio.gather(*arrayOfFutures)
  ```
- Use threadsafe functions to submit tasks to event loops across threads.  For example, instead of creating a run loop for each thread you could run all async coroutines in the main thread's run loop:

  ```
   def threadWork(obj, loop):
       b = do_something()
       if b:
           future_a = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(do_a(), loop)
           future_b = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(do_b(), loop)
           concurrent.futures.wait([future_a, future_b])

   async def startLoop():
       loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
       while 1:
           arrayOfFutures = []
           for item in clients:
               arrayOfFutures.append(asyncio.run_in_executor(
                   config.threadPool, threadWork, item, loop))

           await asyncio.gather(*arrayOfFutures)
  ```

  *Note:* This example should not be used literally as it will result in all coroutines executing in the main thread while the thread pool workers just block. This is just to show an example of the `run_coroutine_threadsafe()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helper class which allows submitting async work for execution in another thread. I originally used the `ThreadPoolExecutor` from `concurrent.futures`, but I find it ends up being simpler to manage the async event loop if you create the threads yourself. Conceptually, it is similar to @augurar's first solution, where we are creating an event loop for each thread. However, here we're using `run_coroutine_threadsafe` to submit tasks to the pool.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from threading import Thread
import asyncio, time, typing
if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from concurrent.futures import Future
    from asyncio import AbstractEventLoop

class AsyncThreadPool:
    """ Thread pool for running async future/coroutines """
    def __init__(self, workers:int=1):
        self.workers: int = workers
        """ Number of worker threads in the pool """
        self.threads: list[Thread] = []
        """ Running threads in the pool """
        self.loops: list[AbstractEventLoop] = []
        """ Event loops for each thread """
        self.roundrobin: int = 0
        """ Next thread to run something in, for round-robin scheduling """

        # initialize threads
        for i in range(workers):
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            self.loops.append(loop)
            thread = Thread(target=loop.run_forever)
            thread.start()
            self.threads.append(thread)

    def run(self, target: typing.Coroutine | typing.Future, worker: int|None=None) -> Future:
        """ Run async future/coroutine in the thread pool
        
            :param target: the future/coroutine to execute
            :param worker: worker thread you want to run the callable; None for round-robin
                selection of worker thread
            :return: future with result
        """
        if worker is None:
            worker = self.roundrobin
            self.roundrobin = (worker + 1) % self.workers
        return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(target, self.loops[worker])
    
    def join(self, timeout:float=.1):
        """ Blocking call to close the thread pool
        
            :param timeout: timeout for polling a thread to check if its async tasks are all finished
        """
        for i in range(self.workers):
            # wait for completion of pending tasks before stopping;
            # stop only waits for current batch of callbacks to complete
            loop = self.loops[i]
            while len(asyncio.all_tasks(loop)):
                time.sleep(timeout)
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)
            self.threads[i].join()
```

Example usage:

```py
async def work():
    print("async work")

# initialize pool
pool = AsyncThreadPool()
# submit to pool
future = pool.run(work())
# block waiting for results
future.result()
# shutdown pool
pool.join()
```