# How to use multiple threadpools in twisted with coroutines

Tags: python, twisted

I want to use a separate threadPool in Python Twisted for some special kind of work that is hard on CPU usage.

The functions I want to execute are all defined as inlineCallback and I can not modify that.

```py
from twisted.python.threadpool import ThreadPool

@inflineCallbacks
def myFunc(i):
    tmp_result = yield intenseCPUwork(i)
    # more work ...
    return result

pool = ThreadPool(0, 2)

for i in range(100):
    pool.callInThread(myFunc, i)

...
```

But since my functions return a deferred they return immediately when called like that in the threadpool resulting in all 100 calls to be executed at once even though the threadPool has just size 2.

How can I ensure only two async functions being called at the same time in twisted?

Comment: Are you aware that multiple threads running Python code compete for execution on a single CPU core?

Comment: Yes, I am. The intenseCPUWork function opens subprocesses that are deferedToThread. They also may trigger work load on other computers.

Comment: Mixing multithreading and multiprocessing?  That's a recipe for disaster.  Twisted has process management APIs though.  Use those instead of threads and you'll be fine.

Comment: I voted to close because the question doesn't actually contain enough information to provide a good example.  I suggest editing it to include all relevant information and then maybe someone can provide a good answer!

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am going to avoid disaster and find a more natural way to handle that instead of trying to force this approach into a working version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The functions I want to execute are all defined as inlineCallback and I can not modify that.

This means you can't run them in a non-reactor thread.  Except for a couple exceptions (mostly having to do with logging or thread management) Twisted APIs are not thread-safe.  You can only use them in the same thread as the reactor is running.

If you cannot change the target functions to stop using Twisted APIs, you cannot run them in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

i believe what you need is async/await support of functions for intense works, it would be something like below

```
import asyncio

async def myFunc(i):
    tmp_result = yield intenseCPUwork(i)
    # more work ...
    return result

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [
    loop.create_task(myFunc(1)),
    loop.create_task(myFunc(2))
]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to solve this in Twisted. For asyncio there is also an answer in that direction here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54761932/2301643.